# vuejs - assigning variable with value as variable name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some variables

```
data() {
    return {
      resData: {},
      datData: {},
      .....
    };
},
```

then I have method that need to assign values to `resData` and etc.
If `name` has value of `resData` then I need to assign value to the variable.

```
methods:{
  chgValue(name){
      if (name == 'resData') this.resData = 1;
      elseif .....
      else
  }
}
```

Instead of doing multiple `if else` statements, I'm trying to do something:

```
methods:{
  chgValue(name){
      this.window[name] = 1;
  }
}
```

But I receive error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'resData' of undefined

Any ways that i could achieve the method ?

Comment: It should be `this[name] = 1`. Not sure where you got `window` from. Even better would be `this.$set(this, name, 1)`, that way you're guaranteed to be setting a reactive property

Comment: @Phil yes u r right, i found the `window` from other threads for using reference variable

Comment: I can see where you got that from. I hope the linked post makes sense for you